Access Violation when calling WinAPI's InternetOpenA() from assembly
I'm trying to establish an HTTP connection from assembly using the Windows API.
The code is the following:
%include "const.asm"
%define u(x) __utf16__(x) 
%define w(x) __utf32__(x) 

; Externs
extern InternetOpenA

extern GetLastError

section .data
    curProc   db 0
    hInternet dq 0

    lpszAgent db "Mozilla/5.0", 0

section .text
global Start
Start:
    sub rsp, 8

    sub rsp, 32 + 1 * 8
    lea rcx, [REL lpszAgent]                            ; lpszAgentW (WIDE STRING)
    mov rdx, 4        ; dwAccessType (DWORD)
    mov r8,  NULL                                       ; lpszProxy (DWORD)
    mov r9,  NULL                                       ; pszProxyBypassW (DWORD)
    mov dword [rsp + 4 * 8], NULL                       ; dwFlags (DWORD)
    call InternetOpenA

    mov [REL hInternet], rax 
    add rsp, 32 + 1 * 8                                 ; hInternet parameter
    cmp rax, NULL
    je error_handler

    ; Stop
    jmp exit


error_handler:
    sub rsp, 32
    call GetLastError                                    ; Load more error info
    add rsp, 32 + 8
    ret


exit:                                                    ; Graceful shutdowns
    xor rax, rax
    add rsp, 8
    ret


The corresponding Makefile is:
INCLUDES := kernel32.lib user32.lib wininet.lib

.PHONY: all compile link clean

all: build

compile:
    @echo "Compiling assembly"
    nasm -f win64 main.asm -o main.o

link: compile
    @echo "Linking assembly"
    polink /ENTRY:Start /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE /LIBPATH:C:\lib64 $(INCLUDES) main.o

build: link

clean:
    @echo "Cleaning up"
    del main.o

When I'm running it, the error code returned is -1073741819 or 0xC0000005 as @selbie pointed out, or also known as Access Violation. I've received segfault for both wininet and winhttp while creating the handle. I'm attaching a short C code showing exactly what I would like to do:
(The assembly should not have the prints. It is just in the C source for debug purposes)
#include "windows.h"
#include "wininet.h"
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    const char *agent = "Mozilla/5.0";
    HINTERNET handler =  InternetOpenA(agent, INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PRECONFIG_WITH_NO_AUTOPROXY, 0, 0, 0);
    if (handler) {
        return 0;
    }
    printf("%d", GetLastError());
    return 1;
}

Just for clarity, I am compiling for 64-bit Windows. I am also statically linking as seen in the Makefile.
Cheers
Edit: Code for some debugging:
[BITS 64]

%include "const.asm"
%define u(x) __utf16__(x) 
%define w(x) __utf32__(x) 

; Externs
extern InternetOpenA

extern GetLastError

extern GetStdHandle
extern WriteFile

section .data
    curProc   db 0
    hInternet dq 0

    lpszAgent db "Mozilla/5.0", 0

    NtlpBuffer:        db    'Hello, World!', 0
    NtnNBytesToWrite:  dq    0eh


section .text
global Start
Start:

    sub rsp, 8
    mov rax, rsp    
    mov rbx, 8 
    xor rdx, rdx
    div rbx
    cmp rdx, 0
    je main

    sub rsp, 32 + 1 * 8
    and rsp, -16
    lea rcx, [REL lpszAgent]                            ; lpszAgentW (WIDE STRING)
    mov rdx, 4                                          ; dwAccessType (DWORD)
    mov r8,  NULL                                       ; lpszProxy (DWORD)
    mov r9,  NULL                                       ; pszProxyBypassW (DWORD)
    mov dword [rsp + 4 * 8], NULL                       ; dwFlags (DWORD)
    
    call InternetOpenA

    mov [REL hInternet], rax 
    add rsp, 32 + 1 * 8                                 ; hInternet parameter
    cmp rax, NULL
    je error_handler

    ; Stop
    jmp exit


error_handler:
    sub rsp, 32
    call GetLastError                                    ; Load more error info
    add rsp, 32 + 8
    ret


exit:                                                    ; Graceful shutdowns
    xor rax, rax
    add rsp, 8
    ret

main:
    sub     rsp, 32
    mov     ecx, -11
    call    GetStdHandle

    mov     rcx, rax
    lea rdx, [rel NtlpBuffer]
    mov     r8, [REL NtnNBytesToWrite]
    mov     r9, NULL
    mov     qword [rsp + 32], 00h
    call    WriteFile
    add     rsp, 32

ExitProgram:
    xor     eax, eax
    add rsp, 8
    ret


-1073741819 is 0xC0000005

add rsp, 32 + 1 * 8 - you do know that stdcall functions exported by the Windows API restore the stack pointer on behalf of the caller. Are you sure your call to restore rsp is neccessary?

@selbie RE first comment, thanks for the clarification, edited. RE 2: I am not aware of that fact. I've been using add rsp, 32 + n * 8 for previous projects and it worked out fine. That being said, the error happens right when I call InternetOpenA. Also, thank you for your quick reply.

Is this 32-bit or 64-bit code?

@selbie 64-bit. Regarding the argument about stack pointer restoration: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/prolog-and-epilog?view=msvc-170. Both prolog and epilog modify the stack pointer manually

@selbie: Windows x64 is caller-pops, so you can allocate the shadow space (plus arg-passing space if necessary) once for a function that makes multiple calls, so RSP never moves outside prologue/epilogue (other than the call itself), making stack-unwind metadata simpler.

If Start is called as a normal function, your prologue misaligns the stack - the total change to RSP from the two sub instructions is an even multiple of 8.  But since call pushed a return address, you need an odd multiple of 8 to get from RSP % 16 == 8 on entry to RSP % 16 == 0 before a call.  Code in a library function that uses movaps on stack memory will fault if you get this wrong, like on Linux which has the same alignment requirement (glibc scanf Segmentation faults when called from a function that doesn't align RSP)

@Peter Cordes Thank you for your quick response! I read your answer and tried to sub rsp, 8 again to have an odd multiple of 8. It still segfault-ed. I might be misinterpreting your solution on the other issue.

Ok, so that's probably not your bug.  Use a debugger to find out which instruction faults.

The stack-pointer changes in your function seem over-complicated.  You don't need different adjustments in different branches, just allocate enough in the prologue and remove it in both epilogues.  (add rsp, 32  + 8*1)

@Peter Cordes are you sure about that? Without it, I cannot call e.g. a print. I tested it by   removing the epilogue after the print, but it gives me segfault. When I place back the epilogue, it works.

@Peter Cordes I added some debugging code in the question. This code runs without a problem, printing Hello World! and returning with zero. This also check the rsp by looking at the remainder. I'm struggeling to set up a debugger: gdb doesn't seem to recognize nasm and polink/link debug headers.

In GDB, use layout asm to debug based on disassembly of the machine code.  You don't need debug metadata.  (And then layout next to see a split view with disassembly and registers.  See the bottom of https://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info for GDB asm tips)

After hours of trying and failing, a fellow assembly programmer, @sbdswr, from Discord helped me debugging it -- funnily enough without any debugger. The problem indeed lay in my stack pointer handling as @Peter Cordes already pointed out. Here is the full version of the fixed code. Thank you for your help!
BITS 64

%include "const.asm"
%define u(x) __utf16__(x) 
%define w(x) __utf32__(x) 

; Externs
extern InternetOpenA

extern GetLastError

extern GetStdHandle
extern WriteFile

extern ExitProcess

section .data
    curProc   db 0
    hInternet dq 0

    lpszAgent db "Mozilla/5.0", 0

    NtlpBuffer:        db    'Hello, World!', 0
    NtnNBytesToWrite:  dq    0eh


section .text
global Start
Start:
    push    rbp
    mov     rbp, rsp
    sub     rsp, 48
    
    lea     rcx, [REL lpszAgent]                            ; lpszAgentW (WIDE STRING)
    mov     rdx, 4                                          ; dwAccessType (DWORD)
    mov     r8,  NULL                                       ; lpszProxy (DWORD)
    mov     r9,  NULL                                       ; pszProxyBypassW (DWORD)
    mov     dword [rsp + 4 * 8], NULL                       ; dwFlags (DWORD)
    call    InternetOpenA
    
    mov     [REL hInternet], rax                            ; hInternet parameter
    cmp     rax, NULL
    je      error_handler

    jmp     exit


error_handler:
    call    GetLastError                                    ; Load more error info
    jmp     exit


exit:
    call    print
    xor     rcx, rcx
    call    ExitProcess
    
print:
    sub     rsp, 40
    mov     ecx, -11
    call    GetStdHandle

    mov     rcx, rax
    lea     rdx, [rel NtlpBuffer]
    mov     r8, [REL NtnNBytesToWrite]
    mov     r9, NULL
    mov     qword [rsp + 32], 00h
    call    WriteFile
    add     rsp, 40
    ret

